# My CRTP mathematical array class : compilation fails

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, crtp

I am currently writing library to deal with little math vectors and matrices and some special functions for my research domain. I am currently testing some CRTP tricks. The following code produces and error at the last line, and I don't know why :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <type_traits>

// Abstract class
template<class TCRTP, class T, unsigned int TSIZE> class AbstractArray
{
    // Constructor
    public:
        inline AbstractArray() : _data{}
        {
            std::cout<<"AbstractArray::AbstractArray()"<<std::endl;
        }

    // Copy constructor
    public:
        template<class TCRTP0, class T0> inline AbstractArray(const AbstractArray<TCRTP0, T0, TSIZE> &rhs)
        {
            std::cout<<"AbstractArray::AbstractArray(const AbstractArray<TCRTP0, T0, TSIZE> &rhs)"<<std::endl;
            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < TSIZE; ++i) {
                _data[i] = rhs[i];
            }
        }

    // Initializer list constructor
    public:
        template<class T0> inline AbstractArray(const std::initializer_list<T0>& rhs)
        {
            std::cout<<"AbstractArray::AbstractArray(const std::initializer_list<T0>& rhs)"<<std::endl;
            const T0* it = rhs.begin();
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < TSIZE; ++i) {
                _data[i] = *it;
                ++it;
            }
        }

    // Destructor
    public:
        inline ~AbstractArray()
        {
            std::cout<<"AbstractArray::~AbstractArray()"<<std::endl;
        }

    // Subscript operator
    public:
        inline const T& operator[](const unsigned int i) const
        {
            std::cout<<"AbstractArray::operator[](const unsigned int i) const"<<std::endl;
            return _data[i];
        }
        inline T& operator[](const unsigned int i)
        {
            std::cout<<"AbstractArray::operator[](const unsigned int i)"<<std::endl;
            return _data[i];
        }

    // Assignment operator
    public:
        template<class TCRTP0, class T0> inline AbstractArray<TCRTP, T, TSIZE>& operator=(const AbstractArray<TCRTP0, T0, TSIZE>& rhs)
        {
            std::cout<<"AbstractArray::operator=(const AbstractArray<TCRTP0, T0, TSIZE>& rhs)"<<std::endl;
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < TSIZE; ++i) {
                _data[i] = rhs[i];
            }
            return *this;
        }

    // Sum assignment
    public:
        template<class TCRTP0, class T0> inline AbstractArray<TCRTP, T, TSIZE>& operator+=(const AbstractArray<TCRTP0, T0, TSIZE>& rhs)
        {
            std::cout<<"AbstractArray::operator+=(const AbstractArray<TCRTP0, T0, TSIZE>& rhs)"<<std::endl;
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < TSIZE; ++i) {
                _data[i] += rhs[i];
            }
            return *this;
        }

    // Sum operator
    public:
        template<class T0> inline AbstractArray<TCRTP, typename std::common_type<T, T0>::type, TSIZE> operator+(const AbstractArray<TCRTP, T0, TSIZE>& rhs) const
        {
            return AbstractArray<TCRTP, typename std::common_type<T, T0>::type, TSIZE>(*this) += rhs;
        }

    // Data members
    protected:
        T _data[TSIZE];
};

// Array class
template<class T, unsigned int TSIZE> class NArray : public  AbstractArray<NArray<T, TSIZE>, T, TSIZE>
{
    // Constructor
    public:
        inline NArray() : AbstractArray<NArray<T, TSIZE>, T, TSIZE>()
        {
            std::cout<<"NArray::NArray()"<<std::endl;
        }

    // Copy constructor
    public:
        template<class TCRTP0, class T0> inline NArray(const AbstractArray<TCRTP0, T0, TSIZE> &rhs) : AbstractArray<NArray<T, TSIZE>, T, TSIZE>(rhs)
        {
            std::cout<<"NArray::NArray(const AbstractArray<TCRTP0, T0, TSIZE> &rhs)"<<std::endl;
        }

    // Initializer list constructor
    public:
        template<class T0> inline NArray(const std::initializer_list<T0>& rhs) : AbstractArray<NArray<T, TSIZE>, T, TSIZE>(rhs)
        {
            std::cout<<"NArray::NArray(const std::initializer_list<T0>& rhs)"<<std::endl;
        }

    // Destructor
    public:
        inline ~NArray()
        {
            std::cout<<"NArray::~NArray()"<<std::endl;
        }
};

// Vector class
template<class T, unsigned int TSIZE> class NVector : public  AbstractArray<NVector<T, TSIZE>, T, TSIZE>
{
    // Constructor
    public:
        inline NVector() : AbstractArray<NVector<T, TSIZE>, T, TSIZE>()
        {
            std::cout<<"NVector::NVector()"<<std::endl;
        }

    // Copy constructor
    public:
        template<class TCRTP0, class T0> inline NVector(const AbstractArray<TCRTP0, T0, TSIZE> &rhs) : AbstractArray<NVector<T, TSIZE>, T, TSIZE>(rhs)
        {
            std::cout<<"NVector::NVector(const AbstractArray<TCRTP0, T0, TSIZE> &rhs)"<<std::endl;
        }

    // Initializer list constructor
    public:
        template<class T0> inline NVector(const std::initializer_list<T0>& rhs) : AbstractArray<NVector<T, TSIZE>, T, TSIZE>(rhs)
        {
            std::cout<<"NVector::NVector(const std::initializer_list<T0>& rhs)"<<std::endl;
        }

    // Destructor
    public:
        inline ~NVector()
        {
            std::cout<<"NVector::~NVector()"<<std::endl;
        }
};

// Main
int main()
{
    NArray<double, 3> a1({1., 2., 3.});
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    NArray<int, 3> a2({4., 5., 6.});
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    NArray<double, 3> a3({7., 8., 9.});
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    NVector<double, 3> v1({11., 12., 13.});
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    NVector<double, 3> v2({14., 15., 16.});
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    NVector<double, 3> v3({17., 18., 19.});
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    NVector<int, 3> v4({20., 21., 22.});
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    a1 = a2;
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"TEST -> a1 = "<<a1[0]<<" "<<a1[1]<<" "<<a1[2]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    v1 = a2;
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"TEST -> v1 = "<<v1[0]<<" "<<v1[1]<<" "<<v1[2]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    v1 += a2;
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"TEST -> v1 = "<<v1[0]<<" "<<v1[1]<<" "<<v1[2]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    v1 = a3+a3;
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"TEST -> v1 = "<<v1[0]<<" "<<v1[1]<<" "<<v1[2]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    //v2 = v3+v4; // <- This line does not work : "error : no match for "operator+" in "v3+v4"
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How to solve the problem ?
And furthemore a question for experts : do you think that this way of coding operators is efficient, or do you have in mind some modifications that can improve the quality of the code ?
Any advice will be appreciated before I start to modify my current implementation with CRTP.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can <strike>fix</strike> make this compile this by using:

```
v2 = v3.operator+<int> (v4);
```

instead of

```
v2 = v3+v4; // <- This line does not work : "error : no match for
```

I have explicitly told the compiler what that `T0` is `int`.  I have done this by using `.operator+<int>`.

**But**, there may be another subtle problem.  In the definition of `operator+`, we see that it takes a `const AbstractArray<TCRTP, T0, TSIZE>& rhs` as argument.  In this case `T0 == int` and `TSIZE == 3`, which is good; but the problem is that `TCRTP` is still defined to be `NVector<double,3>` when perhaps it should be `NVector<int,3>`?

In summary, it is possible to explicitly tell the compiler the template parameters.  But that raises two questions:

- Even if you manually specify the types, are they the correct types? Should you have a distinct `TCRTP` and `TCRTP0` as is used in `operator+=`
- How do we automatically infer the (correct) types?

Comment: Is conversion to the base class (`NVector`->`AbstractArray`) considered in template argument deduction for `operator+`? I guess it shouldn't.

Comment: Good question Andrey.  But I think I've found a problem with my solution.

Comment: Your "But" is a very good point. In fact changing the definition by : "template<class TCRTP0, class T0> inline AbstractArray<TCRTP, typename std::common_type<T, T0>::type, TSIZE> operator+(const AbstractArray<TCRTP0, T0, TSIZE>& rhs) const" works well ! Do you see any problem (like not-ultra-safe-things) in the current implementation or all is OK (because my library will basically rely on this) ?